# Weighted coin probability

Tags: probability

i'm having difficulty answering the following probability question...

Suppose two players, A and B take turns rolling a die. The first one who obtains a 3 wins. If A goes first what is the probability that A wins? What is the probability that B wins?

I can't really come up with a way of solving it without listing out the probabilities of each turn. It would be great if you guys can lead me in the direction of the solution! thanks.

Comment: I think that if A goes first and rolls on 1,2,4 (3 of the wrong rolls, then B automatically wins) For this to happen, A has a probability of 3/5 of getting the wrong roll whereas B would only have a 2/5th probability of getting the wrong roll. However, this is the case where they exhaust all dice rolls in which the dice rolls on each number. I can't seem to understand how this plays a roll in the solution because if A goes first, he obviously has a better chance of getting a 3 before B does.

Comment: "I can't really come up with a way of solving it without listing out the probabilities of each turn" The accepted answer does exactly that (listing out the probabilities of each turn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of rolling a $1,2,4,5,$ or $6$ is $(5/6)$, so the probability of only rolling $\lnot3$ after $n$ turns is $(5/6)^n$.  Thus, the probability a $3$ is rolled on the $n^\mathrm{th}$ turn is $\frac{5}{6}^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

The probability of A rolling the first 3 is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5}{6}^{(2k+1)-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1-\frac{25}{36}}=\frac{6}{11} $$

Comment: And probability of B winning is $1-{6/11}$ ??

Comment: Yes, since that is the only other option, B has $5/11$ chance of winning.

Answer (score 0):

Say that player A wins with probability $p$. This happens when, either the first roll yields a 3, or the first roll does not yield a 3 but player B loses starting from the second throw.

By symmetry, this last event happens with conditional probability $1-p$, hence $p=\frac16+\frac56(1-p)$, that is, $p=$ $____$.

*Sanity check:* (Easy) $p\gt\frac12$ (why?). (More elaborate) The value of $p$ using a die with $N$ faces goes to $\frac12$ when $N\to\infty$ (why?).

Answer (score 0):

A's probability of winning at the first throw is $\frac16$ = $\frac6{36}$.
B's probability of winning at his first throw is $\frac56 * \frac16 = \frac5{36}$
If you continue this process you'll see that the ratio remains $6:5$.
A has a $\frac6{11}$ probability of winning.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if a wins with probability $p$ then if A rolls

- correctly, he wins immediately (prob. 1/6)
- incorrectly (which happens
  with probability $5/6$), then B wins with the same probability $p$ -
  so A loses with probability $1-p$.

So you have
$$
\begin{split}
p  &= \frac{1}{6} + \frac{5}{6} (1-p) \\
6p &= 1 + 5-5p \\
p  &= 6/11
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat slick way of thinking about things.  The game is played in *rounds*, where a round consists of A rolling the die and then B rolling the die.  If neither player rolls a $3$, the game goes into the next round.  If either player rolls a $3$, the game is over, with the first player to roll the $3$ in that round declared the winner.  I.e., allow player B to roll the die even when player A has already won the game!

We need only consider the possibilities for the last round.  There are $11$ of them:  either A rolls the winning $3$ and B rolls anything (including a $3$), or B rolls the winning $3$ after A rolls a non-$3$.  These are all equally likely, and A wins $6$ of them while B wins 5, for probabilities $6/11$ and $5/11$, respectively.

**Added later**:  One advantage to this approach is that it lends itself to easy generalization to more complicated-seeming problems without the need to set up or solve any equations.  For example, suppose the game cycles among *four* players, A, B, C, and D, until one of them rolls a $3$.  Then A has $1\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6=216$ ways to win the final round, B has $5\cdot1\cdot6\cdot6=180$ ways to win it, C has $5\cdot5\cdot1\cdot6=150$ ways to win, and D has $5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot1=125$ ways.  Simply summing $216+180+150+125=671$, one obtains the probabilities ${216\over617}$, ${180\over671}$, ${150\over671}$, and ${125\over671}$, respectively.